# Display image based on screen size

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have the following image which is `550X257` in `drawable` folder:
[image]

It appears differently for different size screen:
[image]

How do I ensure it fills the parent width no matter what the device is being used. To test it I made the image larger proportionally and put it inside different Density folder but the images comes out even smaller on the bigger screen.

My XML looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bd" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you read the guide [Supporting Multiple Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Yes I have and how does DP compared to pixel in a graphic editing program. I englarged the image proportionally and put it inside the XHPDI folder which is what the larger screen uses and it becomes even smaller than what's shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

first is convert the image for different dpi devices(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xdpi) and put the image in folders drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xdpi

above method may not work perfect for you

second method is you detect the size of the device and set the width and height of image accordingly in pixels

Detect screensize by this method

```
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm= new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(dm);
    Log.i("widthxheight",dm.widthPixels+"x"+dm.heightPixels;
```

now i hope you can determine the width of the image by using either the widthPixels or heightPixels like this: `int imgwidth=(int)(widthPixels*0.80);//80 percent of width`
and calculate the height in same ratio: `int imgheight=(imgwidth*originalimageheight)/originalimagewidth;`

after this you can set the width height of image programmatically using LayoutParameters

Comment: Which method would be best? Also If i resize the image, what size should I resize it to? Also do you know where there is a padding on the Nexus on the bottom?

Comment: What folder is used for the Tablet that is 10" and for 7"?

Comment: well it depends
dpi is different thing and screen size is different

Comment: suppose the device is mdpi and screen size is 10 inch then the foldername will be drawable-mdpi-xlarge
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
check this article for naming folder guide and understanding screen sizes and dpi difference
Sorry for late reply

Comment: about above questions: if you want the image to be in same proportion for all devices then the manual scaling method(second method in answer is best) but if you don't want them to be exactly the same then placing different images in folders(drawable-hdpi etc) is best and easy approach
About the padding of bottom bar "heightPixels" don't include the padding i.e. if device height is 800px and bottom bar is 40px then heightPixels value will be 760px

Comment: I used the dimension folder for each image and it worked out for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

To:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Appropriately for your ImageView.

Comment: The `layout_width` only stretches the imageview not the image itself. I am trying to stretch the image

Comment: if the image is not stretched then you can try the scaletype attribute of the imageview, it tells the imageview how to scale the bitmap i think if you use the match_parent then use scaletype as fitCenter
also you can set the padding in dp for uniform scaling